# Scrollbar flicker when calling EnableScrollBar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scroll, pinvoke

I'm using p/invoke to call `EnableScrollBar` from `user32.dll` ([MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787579%28VS.85%29.aspx)). I noticed that when the scrollbar is enabled, it seems to draw as though no theme is applied and then re-drawn with the theme applied. I've only tested with Windows 7 so far. Is there 
any way to stop this from happening?

**EDIT:** Here's some code to show what happens (dump into a form with scrollbars):

```
private class Native
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool EnableScrollBar(IntPtr hWnd, uint wSBflags, uint wArrows);

    public static class SBArrows
    {
        public const uint ESB_ENABLE_BOTH = 0;
        public const uint ESB_DISABLE_BOTH = 3;
        public const uint ESB_DISABLE_LEFT = 1;
        public const uint ESB_DISABLE_RIGHT = 2;
        public const uint ESB_DISABLE_UP = 1;
        public const uint ESB_DISABLE_DOWN = 2;
        public const uint ESB_DISABLE_LTUP = 1;
        public const uint ESB_DISABLE_RTDN = 2;
    }

    public static class SBFlags
    {
        public const uint SB_HORZ = 0;
        public const uint SB_VERT = 1;
        public const uint SB_CTL = 2;
        public const uint SB_BOTH = 3;
    }
}


private bool Switch = false;

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Native.EnableScrollBar(this.Handle, Native.SBFlags.SB_HORZ, this.Switch ? Native.SBArrows.ESB_DISABLE_BOTH : Native.SBArrows.ESB_ENABLE_BOTH);
    this.Switch = !this.Switch;
}
```

#### Final Solution

```
Native.SendMessage(this.Handle, Native.WindowMessages.WM_SETREDRAW, new IntPtr(0), IntPtr.Zero);
Native.EnableScrollBar(this.Handle, Native.SBFlags.SB_HORZ, Native.SBArrows.ESB_ENABLE_BOTH);
Native.SendMessage(this.Handle, Native.WindowMessages.WM_SETREDRAW, new IntPtr(1), IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: You need to document this better, at least with some repro code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like this solution much.  It does however work:

```
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
        Native.LockWindowUpdate(this.Handle);
        Native.EnableScrollBar(this.Handle, Native.SBFlags.SB_HORZ, this.Switch ? Native.SBArrows.ESB_DISABLE_BOTH : Native.SBArrows.ESB_ENABLE_BOTH);
        //this.Invalidate();
        Native.LockWindowUpdate(IntPtr.Zero);
        this.Switch = !this.Switch;
    }
```

Comment: @Hans - That does the trick. Could you enlighten me as to why you don't like this solution? I'm trying to learn as much as possible about native methods. Thanks!

Comment: Link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/02/22/1742084.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: Thanks! I just found that link and the others blog series on it, too. So sending the `WM_SETREDRAW` message would obviously be better, correct?

Comment: @Hans - After some tests, I'm sure that sending the `WM_SETREDRAW` message does seem to work.