# Mimic Disabled Focus Behaviour in WinForms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In accordance to [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873583/enabled-scrollbar-in-a-disabled-textbox-in-vb-net-for-winforms) I'm trying to mimic the behavior of

```
Enabled = False
```

without actually disable the Control. (In my case a multiline TextBox)

The next I'm trying to accomplish is to mimic the focus behavior by mouse of a disabled control. If I click on a disabled control it won't get the focus and the control that    previously had focus won't loose the focus.

What I came up with so far: I can intercept the WM_SETFOCUS message in WndProc so my control won't recieve focus.

```
Private Const WM_SETFOCUS = &H7

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If Me.ReadOnly AndAlso (m.Msg = WM_SETFOCUS) Then Exit Sub
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

The problem with that is, that the previous contol lost the focus, which isn't intended. How do I prevent that even the click by mouse will do anything in the focus behaviour? Is there any way to do this?

**Update: 06.08.12**

As suggested by Justin I solved the problem by changing it to a label in an autoscroll panel. A minimal code example is as followed:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class ScrollableDisabledTextBox
    Inherits TextBox

    Private xLabel As Label
    Private xPanel As Panel

    Public Sub New()
        InizializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub InizializeComponent()
        xPanel = New Panel
        xPanel.AutoScroll = True
        xPanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle

        xLabel = New Label
        xLabel.Enabled = False
        xLabel.AutoSize = True
        xPanel.Controls.Add(xLabel)

        Me.Me_SizeChanged()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Me_EnabledChanged() Handles Me.EnabledChanged
        If Me.Enabled Then
            Me.Show()
            xPanel.Hide()
        Else
            xPanel.Show()
            Me.SendToBack()
            Me.Hide()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Me_TextChanged() Handles Me.TextChanged
        xLabel.Text = Me.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub Me_SizeChanged() Handles Me.SizeChanged
        xPanel.Size = Me.Size
        xLabel.MaximumSize = New System.Drawing.Size(xPanel.Size.Width, 0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Me_ParentChanged() Handles Me.ParentChanged
        xPanel.Location = Me.Location
        'If parent changed multiple times, remember to remove panel from old parent!
        If Not Me.Parent.Controls.Contains(xPanel) Then
            Me.Parent.Controls.Add(xPanel)
        End If
    End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe what you want to do is possible. If you do not have focus, then the scrolling will not work.

However, I posit that you should rethink your original problem. Why not use an `AutoSize = true, MaximumSize.Width = ParentWidth` label  (which could be disabled) inside of a panel that will autoscroll. This sounds like what you are really looking for.

Comment: This would also need some way to emulate the textbox's disabled scrollbar/s (when the panel's scrollbars disappear) and border colour. Nevertheless, I think it would be a far more manageable approach than the OP's. +1

Comment: @Justin Nice idea, but I do need a TextBox because users should also be able to insert text. I don't see that possible with your solution.

Comment: @Marvin I think what Justin is suggesting is that you position the panel in the same place as the textbox and swap their visibility at the times when you need to emulate a disabled textbox that can still be scrolled.

Comment: Okay, I tried it and it worked perfect. I'll post the minimal code in my example.